# API state design pattern in python

Tags: python, django, design-patterns

As I understood, Is the following code sufficient for the attached question? please need your help to clarify the missing points or parts, should I add some exceptions catching, should **edit_title** & **edit_description** be only in the **New** class() or abstract in the **TaskAPI** class() and override it inside child classes , should i use the Django rest framework API, below the in-progress state is written 'link two tasks you should be able to call both of them using any id' what does that mean.

```
    # States of a Task

class TaskAPI(object):
    """ Abstract base class of state of a task """

    name = "state"
    allowed = []

    def switch(self, state):
        """ Switch to new state """
        if state.name in self.allowed:
            print('Current:', self, ' => switched to new state', state.name)
            self.__class__ = state
            # print( self.__class__)
        else:
            print('Current:', self, ' => switching to', state.name, 'not possible.')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name



class New(TaskAPI):
    """ New State being in progress """

    name = "New"
    allowed = ['InProgress']

    def edit_title(self,new_title):
        self.title = new_title

    def edit_description(self,new_description):
        self.new_description = new_description

class InProgress(TaskAPI):
    """ State of being in progress after New state and need to switched to be done """

    name = "InProgress"
    allowed = ['Done']


class Done(TaskAPI):
    """ Done State of  task """

    name = "Done"
    allowed = []




class Task(object):
    """ A class representing a Task """

    def __init__(self, id,title,description):
        self.id = id
        self.title = title
        self.description = description
        # State of the computer - default is New.
        self.state = New()

    def change(self, state):
        """ Change state """

        self.state.switch(state)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = Task(1,'task1','test1')


    t1.change(InProgress)
    t1.change(Done)
    print(t1.state.__class__)
    t1.change(InProgress)
    print(t1.title)
    try:
        t1.state.edit_title
    except:
        print('Edit title process not allowed! for {}'.format(t1.state.name),'state')
```

[image]

Comment: The Django Rest Framework does a really good job with api's and they have a bunch of example on the docs.

Comment: does this question needs to use Django Rest framework

Comment: You aren't required to use the Rest Framework, it just makes it easier to code API

Comment: could you share with me a link to code a API

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/#example this is a good example